# How to do calculation between column in pivot table and only show it on specific row in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, calculation

[image: 1]

Hello everyone i need help and i would be thankful for anyone of you that voluntary help me a stranger in need,

I have a pivot table about budget from bank 1 and bank 2 (For bank 2 there is a column beside it that tell us how much check that we gonna received and for bank 1 we can take money from it without any check)

and there is implementation cost
and also column change ( Sum of Bank 1 + Sum of Check Bank 2 - Implementation Cost = Change, the nominal in column change in the picture is wrong btw)

now here is the problem, i need to get the column number of column change, i wanted to make the green square area show the result from number in red area + number in yellow area - number in blue area

if anyone of you know the solution please, do tell me the solution friend

i wanted to make the green square area show the result from number in red area + number in yellow area - number in blue area

Comment: You will have to use a data model with the [Power Pivot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-pivot-overview-and-learning-f9001958-7901-4caa-ad80-028a6d2432ed) Add-in (included in Excel 2013 or above) and define some measures for it.

Comment: Thanks for the information my friend, I'll try to look up and learn Power Pivot, hopefully the rest of your day will be a good day.

Answer (score -1):

> All of you that have the same problem as i am rejoice,

because you can add your own calculation in your pivot,

1. First of all you need to click your Pivot Table
2. Then Click Pivot Table Analyze Tab
3. Click Field, Items, & Sets
4. Then click Calculated Field
5. Now you can make your own calculation, after you make the calculation you click add/ ok
6. Then you can show the calculated field that you make in pivot table using  Show Field List and check the new calculation that you make and drag it to your pivot table field